# Why Unity3D color changes, when I decrease color channels that already is equal to zero?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

This is hot case. In sense that It has no explanation even in suggestions.

So.

I have are cubes in scene.

In cycle I start coroutine for every cube, and this coroutine do next things:

It changes color of cube from black(0, 0, 0) to red(1, 0, 0) and then do revers action. In my code, in part, where I return color from red to black, I decrease values of G and B fields. Why would I do that? I would do that if I forgeted change these lines after copypast from action where I change color from black to red when it was not red, and when I changed R and G and B.

```
private IEnumerator CororRoutine(Material cubeMaterial)
{
    float coff = 1f;

    while (cubeMaterial.color.r < 1.0f)
    {
        cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
            cubeMaterial.color.r + coff * Time.deltaTime,
            0.0f,
            0.0f);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    while (cubeMaterial.color.r > 0.0f)
    {
        cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
            cubeMaterial.color.r - coff * Time.deltaTime,
            cubeMaterial.color.g - coff * Time.deltaTime,
            cubeMaterial.color.b - coff * Time.deltaTime);

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

So, there is a very strange things happens...
Screenshot:
[image]

As you can see, cubes that already have changed in both ways, have a little red shade. BUT. Values in their albedo color in material exactly (0, 0, 0).
On screenshot you can see kind of red shade on material.

If you know something, that can bring me some understanding of what here happened, It would be really helpful.

## Edit_1:

The question is: Why Color changes, when I decrease color channels that already is 0? Do this known to anyone ?
I know that I should not decrease values of channels that already equals to 0.
But it seems very strange when color of material changes when I do it.

Comment: Please provide reasonable title. This is not newspaper.

Comment: What shader are you using? Standard Shader?

Comment: @Programmer Yeah, I am using standard shader with transparent rendering mode.

Comment: And what you want to do is to go from Black to Red then from Red black again. If this is true, is there a wait time between this transition?

Comment: @Programmer As you can see at code, I change the color from black to red whilr color(R) less than 1.0. Then I change in reverse order while color(R) greater than 0.0f, What time do you mean ?

The question is: Why after two transtitions color have a red shade ?
And color values are 0, 0, 0, 1

Comment: You want to change color over time. What during time do you want to spend changing the black to red color?   What during time do you want to spend changing the red to black color?

Comment: @Programmer I do not understand what you ask me about.

I change color to red one time(coroutine in code, during it is not the red), and change color to black one time(the same thing about black)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Color changes, when I decrease color channels that already is 0?
>   Do this known to anyone ? I know that I should not decrease values of
>   channels that already equals to 0. But it seems very strange when
>   color of material changes when I do it.

[ChristF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976660/3785314) and [Le len](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39976486/3785314) have already answered your question. Please read them. Read the negative value stuff they both talked about. That is the problem.

*The only reason I am answering this is because I think you are doing this wrong and both answer did not provide a proper way of changing color*.

Put

```
Debug.Log("R: " + cubeMaterial.color.r);
Debug.Log("G: " + cubeMaterial.color.g);
Debug.Log("B: " + cubeMaterial.color.b);
```

in the second `while` loop. You will notice that RGB value is changing into negative values. I got the value below:

> ```
> R: -0.0210881
> G: -1.026095
> B: -1.026095
> ```

The `color.r`, `color.g`,`color.b` and `color.a` properties **only** allow values from `0.0f` to `1.0f`. You **can't** use value that less than `0f` or value that is greater than `1f`. If you do this, you will get undefined behavior since no one knows how Unity handles values that are out of this range. Do not ask why because this is a rule that is set by Unity. It is as simple as that.

A direct quote from [Unity Doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html):

> This structure is used throughout Unity to pass colors around. Each
>   color component is a floating point value with a range from 0 to 1.

Note that your current while loop cannot prevent values from going below `0` or above `1`.

**SOLUTION**:

You have two options.

**1**.You can use [`Mathf.Clamp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp.html) or [`Mathf.Clamp01`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Clamp01.html) to fix this problem. This will clamp your value between `0` and `1`.

Replace

```
cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
cubeMaterial.color.r - coff * Time.deltaTime,
cubeMaterial.color.g - coff * Time.deltaTime,
cubeMaterial.color.b - coff * Time.deltaTime);
```

with

```
cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
Mathf.Clamp(cubeMaterial.color.r - coff * Time.deltaTime, 0, 1),
Mathf.Clamp(cubeMaterial.color.g - coff * Time.deltaTime, 0, 1),
Mathf.Clamp(cubeMaterial.color.b - coff * Time.deltaTime, 0, 1));
```

**2**.Do this the proper way. You should not increment a color value in the first place. The first solution in this answer is just a hack. The real solution is to use [`Color.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html). This will change between two colors. I highly recommend this solution.

```
private IEnumerator CororRoutine(Material cubeMaterial)
{
    float counter = 0f;
    float changeDuration = 1f;

    Color blackColor = Color.black; //OR new Color(0f,0f,1f);
    Color redColor = Color.red; //OR new Color(1f,0f,0f);

    //Black To Red
    while (counter < changeDuration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        cubeMaterial.color = Color.Lerp(blackColor, redColor, counter / changeDuration);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }

    counter = 0;

    //Red To Black
    while (counter < changeDuration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        cubeMaterial.color = Color.Lerp(redColor, blackColor, counter / changeDuration);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps because you're saying

```
        cubeMaterial.color.g - coff * Time.deltaTime,
        cubeMaterial.color.b - coff * Time.deltaTime);
```

while there already 0

Comment: So, why does it make red shade on cube, when it comes to black(decrease R to zero and decrease G and B when it is ALREADY is zero) ?

Comment: you are speaking of curious results, this is some curious code. i do not know how negative values are handelt by unity, but fact is: you are setting negative values, negative values wich bring out RED as much as possible.

Comment: I just try to get understanding in this certain question(that you talking about): How negative values in color are processed by unity ?

Comment: I don't know how unity handles it. It seems it shows the difference between RGB. But I suggest you simply do not use bad code. It s unacceptable.

Answer (score 0):

> In my code, in part, where I return color from red to black, I decrease values of G and B fields. Why would I do that? I would do that if I forgeted change these lines after copypast from action where I change color from black to red when it was not red, and when I changed R and G and B.

It certainly looks like you forgot to change this code when you copied the code from elsewhere.

If you know for certain that the green and blue components aren't changing then you can simply write:

```
while (cubeMaterial.color.r > 0.0f)
{
    cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
        cubeMaterial.color.r - coff * Time.deltaTime,
        0.0f,
        0.0f);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

If the values might have been changed then you'd want to include a check that the green and blue components weren't already zero before decrementing their values.

There might also be an issue if the value of `coff - Time.deltaTime` is greater than the current `cubeMaterial.color.r`. This will result in a "negative" colour. I don't know even if this will get created successfully.

If it doesn't get created this will leave your object with the last valid colour - a very dark red.

If it does get created then if display code ignores the sign this would explain the very slight red tint to your objects.

You're working with `float` values, which while they are great for speed, they have accuracy issues. I'd add an extra test to set the value to exactly zero when you get close enough:

```
float offset = coff * Time.deltaTime;
while (cubeMaterial.color.r > 0.0f)
{
    cubeMaterial.color = new Color(
        (offset > cubeMaterial.color.r) ? cubeMaterial.color.r - offset : 0.0f,
        0.0f,
        0.0f);

    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: I didn't copy it frim somewhere. I wrote it, and at first time I forgot change those lines of G B color to stay a zero. When it equals to zero it works just fin, But. This is not brings the answer why color of cubes in end of color changing to black stay have a little red shade when I decrease values that equals to zero and can not be decreased?